# Line passing through the origin and incident to two other lines

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

I came across this silly exercise but it's giving me a headache, because I cannot figure whether or not I'm not doing it right.

I have two lines of cartesian equations given

$$
r : \left\{
\begin{array}{l} 
x = 2z - 1 \\ 
y = z + 1
\end{array}\right. \;\;\;
s : \left\{
\begin{array}{l} 
z = 2 \\ 
x + y - 1 = 0
\end{array}\right.
$$

And I need to find the line passing through origin $O = (0,0,0)$ and intersecting both $r$ and $s$.

I don't think the exercise has solution.

My attempt: I wrote both lines in parametric form (I don't think this was necessary but it made the equations a bit easier to read)

$$
r : \left\{
\begin{array}{l} 
x = 2t - 1 \\ 
y = t + 1 \\
z = t
\end{array}\right. \;\;\;
s : \left\{
\begin{array}{l} 
x = -s + 1 \\
y = s \\
z = 2
\end{array}\right.
$$

Then I imposed the collinearity among the origin, generic point for $r$ and generic point for $s$ which is equivalent to impose

$$
\text{rank}
\begin{pmatrix}
2t - 1 & 1 - s \\
t + 1 & s \\
t & 2
\end{pmatrix} = 1
$$

which gave me the system (non linear but easy)

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
2t + 2 - ts = 0 \\
3t - 2 + ts = 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Subtracting the second equation from the first gives me $t = 0$, but substituting this value in any of the two equations gives me a contradiction $1 = 0$, which makes me say there's no such line.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Looks correct to me as long as that collinearity condition with $\text{rank}$ is correct. What was your justification for that?

Comment: actually, I think it's good. The way I am interpreting your idea is that if $A$ and $B$ are on those two lines and the line through them passes through the origin, then $\vec{OA}$ and $\vec{OB}$ are parallel, which means the the two vectors are linearly dependent, so the rank is one.

Comment: @dezdichado yes, I took the generic vector $\vec{OA}$ and the generic vector $\vec{OB}$ and imposing they're parallel through the rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree.  I worked it slightly differently.

$$x_1 -2z_1 = -1$$
$$y_1 - z_1 = 1$$

$$x_2 + y_2 = 1$$
$$z_2 = 2$$

And some scaling of a solution to the first set equals the 2nd set so that we get a line through the origin. $(x_1,y_1,z_1) = c (x_2,y_2,z_2)$.

So substituting:

$$z_1/c = 2$$
$$x_1/c + y_1/c = 1$$
$$z_1 - 2c = 0$$
$$x_1+y_1 -c =0$$

Using the first 2 and last 2 equations I got the solution $(x_1,y_1,z_1,c) = (-1,1,0,0)$

Since $z_1 = c = 0$ there is no scaling that makes a solution.

Comment: Thank you, it was honestly driving me crazy.

Comment: Why so complicated?  We have $z=2$.  Then from the first equation of $r$ we get $x=3$ and from the second $y=3$.  But these solutions don't solve the second equation of $s$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I was trying to find a way to get solution to any of these equations, not just this particular one.